# Set or put in the freezer?

Tags: word-choice, sit-set

Which one is correct?

> A: I set my bottle of water in the freezer.
>   B: I put my bottle of water in the freezer.

Is there any difference?

Comment: Both are correct, but I'd expect to hear (B) more often.

Comment: In general, B sounds more natural.  _Set_ might make sense if the emphasis is on **how** you put it in the freezer.  _I couldn't find the lid, so I set my bottle of water in the freezer upright._ (AmE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been stated, both are correct and there is no significant difference between the two.

However, I might choose "set" over "put" in situations where I placed the object more carefully. If I have a bottle of water with a tight cap on it, I **put** it in the fridge. If I have a crystal bowl with a fancy [trifle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifle) in it, I might **set** it in the fridge.

Comment: I agree.  Well put!  :)

Comment: This native speaker agrees. **Set** (in this context) describes the motion of placing one thing so it sits stably on top of another thing, implying some care and deliberateness in the action. **Put** doesn't suggest anything one way or the other about the motion or how carefully it was performed.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. In fact the definition of 'set' includes the definition of 'put`. They are nearly synonyms in the usage in question.

I do agree with [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41480/set-or-put-in-the-freezer/41481#comment77709_41480) that B ('put') is more common.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use the verb 'keep' for the things which you need to put in the fridge** **regularly.**

For example

1. Do you keep ice the freezer ?
2. Do you keep water bottles in the fridge ?

Here neither 'set' or 'put' is correct.

You'll find the verb 'keep' printed on the medicine bottles and other things which are supposed to be kept in the fridge.

**Definition of 'set' - to put someone or something in a position**

'Set' is preferably used when you are allocating a place for a particular thing or you are setting a paritcular thing in a particular position.

For example

1. Where do you want to set this tv ?

So in your example it is less appropriate to use 'set' because you are not allocating a place to the bottle.

However 'put' should work fine here.